# Use condition on jquery UI slider plugin

Tags: jquery, user-interface, slider

I am using a jquery ui range slider. I want to apply a condition on its value. for eg if the slider head at in 0 I want to show an error message. How can I do that? thanks

This is the plugin link

https://github.com/simeydotme/jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips

Answer (score 0):

actually it has nothing to do with the pips plugin, but you can do with the $.ui.slider plugin using the `slidestop` event:

```
$(".slider")

    .slider({ /* ... */ })

    .slider("pips", { /* ... */ })

    .on( "slidestop", function( event, ui ) {

        if( ui.value === 0 ) {
            /* show error */
        }

    });
```

How this helps you, and I hope you enjoy the pips plugin! :)